# How do I get a paged_table without column types displayed?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I need to print a `paged_table` in a HTML Rmd document, but I don't want the column types displayed.

`?paged_table` indicates that there are printing options, but the only options I can [find documented](https://rstudio.github.io/distill/tables.html)  are about the maximum numbers of rows/columns to print and whether or not to print row names.

Reproducible example in RMD:

````
---
output:
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
editor_options:
  chunk_output_type: inline
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```


```{r cars}
datasets::mtcars
```
````

Comment: What are you printing, and how, and where? Can you add an example?

Comment: @camille title says dataframe, doesn't matter pick any data set. I included an example in the question but it's pretty much overkill...

Comment: @GregorThomas as stated, this is why I'm not using kable, I need paging.

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately column types isn't listed as [one of the options here](https://rstudio.github.io/distill/tables.html), and I'm not finding other documentation on options. I've edited your question to make it clearer that the issue is getting a *paged table* without column types rather than just printing a data frame.

Comment: You could use the DT package instead https://rstudio.github.io/DT/

Comment: @GeorgeDontas I provided the solution below but yes I ended up with the package mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure to install the DT package:

```
install.packages('DT')
```

The following is the RMD code:

````
---
output:
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
editor_options:
  chunk_output_type: inline
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```


```{r cars}
library(DT)
datasets::mtcars
datatable(mtcars)
```
````